# Android how to get file path from /res/raw/

Tags: android

I put my bash script in `/res/raw/` folder in my Android Studio Project. How can I get the path to the file to execute it using exec?

I try to this:

```
InputStream scriptFile = activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file); // script path
```

But I can not get file path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute your bash like this:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(scriptFile));
        String command = "";
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            command = r.readLine();
            commands.add(command);
            while(command != null){
                command = r.readLine();
                commands.add(command);
            }

            Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command(commands).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And you can get the Uri of the raw resource in order to create a new File object:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.your.package/raw/filename");
```

Comment: Ok, but `scriptFile` var is not defined in your example. How do I define it?

Comment: How to get absolute file path?

Comment: You create a new file object with that uri and you can then get it with file.getAbsolutePath();

Answer (score -7):

or you can do like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.html");
```

Comment: This is accessing content in the assets folder and not the raw folder