# androidTest: How to get path of a file in res/raw directory?

Tags: android, android-testing

I have a file in res/raw in the androidTest directory. I want to pass it's path to another method in my test. I tried something like: `android.resource://com.my.package.test/raw/filename`
based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962901/android-how-to-get-file-path-from-res-raw?answertab=active#tab-top) answer but it didn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: There is no path. Resources are files on your development machine. They are not files on the filesystem of the device. `android.resource://com.my.package.test/raw/filename` is a `Uri` value, not a filesystem path.

Answer (score 0):

**androidTest** is able to access the resources by below code:

```
Context context = getInstrumentation().getContext();
context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.your_filename);
```

**Or**

```
Context context = getInstrumentation().getContext();
context.getResources().openRawResource(com.your.package.test.R.raw.your_filename);
```

Comment: This returns InputStream, not the path to the file.